# Unrecognized Syntax in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cocos2d-x

**I am able to build the solution and run the example.**

However, the syntax seems not to be recognized correctly in my visual studio.

Version of cocos2d : 3.14.1.

Version of VS : visual studio 2015 community

[image]

[image]
Does any body has any idea about this problem?

Many thanks

Comment: Pointers to members formally require `&HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback`. As for `Scene`, that's probably unrecognized because the preceding `USING_NS_CC` is also unrecognized.

Comment: Next time, please also post your code, it makes it easier for us to access

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio's IntelliSense uses a different analysis engine than the compiler. It often lags behind. It sometimes disagrees with the compiler.

The compiler is the final authority on what the compiler accepts.

Sometimes time is all the IntelliSense needs. When it chokes on macros I have often (but not always) managed to sort of update its ideas by peeking the definition of the first troublesome use of the macro. Right-click and choose *Peek definition*.

Comment: Thanks, but misleading auto-complete and red wavy line everywhere make me uncomfortable during coding. Is that any way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can turn Intellisense off.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliSense might have not indexed all of your project's code and dependencies and it can't find those underlined symbols. Sometimes it can help to close Visual Studio and delete the indexing database (those big *.sdf files in your solution folder) and restart.

Comment: Many thanks, you answer inspire me a lot. I realize the cocos2d project actually did not create a .sdf file after being built. It will be very appreciated if you could tell me why it is not generated. I checked the option and the "disable database" if false.